# how to query range?

Tags: sql, range

Raw Data

```
| ID  | STATUS      |
|  1  |      A      |
|  2  |      A      |
|  3  |      B      |
|  4  |      B      |
|  5  |      B      |
|  6  |      A      |
|  7  |      A      |
|  8  |      A      |
|  9  |      C      |
```

Result

```
| START      | END    |
|      1     |   2    |
|      6     |   8    |
```

Range of STATUS A

How to query ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it

Comment: I wonder if you mean `SELECT STATUS, MIN(ID) AS LOWER, MAX(ID) AS UPPER FROM RAW_DATA GROUP BY STATUS` ?

Comment: That won't return what OP wants

Comment: Search for SQL queries concerning "islands" and/or "gaps." As @bluefeet says, the specific RDBMS is important in this case.

Comment: @dalarcop - I think we are all guessing a little bit what the OP is asking for.

Comment: yes, but it is amazing how something quite simple is going to be quite painful in mysql...

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the correct ranges:

```
SELECT
  STATUS,
  MIN(ID),
  max_id
FROM (
  SELECT
    t1.STATUS,
    t1.ID,
    COALESCE(MAX(t2.ID), t1.ID) max_id
  FROM
    yourtable t1 LEFT JOIN yourtable t2
    ON t1.STATUS=t2.STATUS AND t1.ID<t2.ID
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                FROM yourtable t3
                WHERE
                  t3.STATUS!=t1.STATUS
                  AND t3.ID>t1.ID AND t3.ID<t2.ID)
  GROUP BY
    t1.ID,
    t1.STATUS
) s
WHERE
  status = 'A'
GROUP BY
  STATUS,
  max_id
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2770d/4).

Comment: As it stands, this cannot return status C.

Comment: @TimLehner thanks a lot.. I forgot to use COALESCE on the subquery, now I edited and it should be ok... thanks again

Comment: +1, thank you for not using a cursor. There are also other possibilities such as [using ranking functions or lag/lead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818604/sql-query-to-group-items-by-time-but-only-if-near-each-other/15818941#comment22501046_15818941), if we knew the target RDBMS.

Comment: I understand the reluctance for cursors, but this may actually be a case when it is worth breaking the rule.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off with a cursor-based solution or a client-side function.

However, if you were using Oracle - the following would work.

```
WITH LOWER_VALS AS
( -- All the Ids with no immediate predecessor
  SELECT ROWNUM AS RN, STATUS, ID AS LOWER FROM
  (
  SELECT STATUS, ID 
  FROM RAWDATA RD1 
  WHERE RD1.ID -1 NOT IN
    (SELECT ID FROM RAWDATA PRED_TABLE WHERE PRED_TABLE.STATUS = RD1.STATUS)
  ORDER BY STATUS, ID
  )
) ,  
UPPER_VALS AS
( -- All the Ids with no immediate successor  
  SELECT ROWNUM AS RN, STATUS, ID AS UPPER FROM
  (
  SELECT STATUS, ID 
  FROM RAWDATA RD2 
  WHERE RD2.ID +1 NOT IN
    (SELECT ID FROM RAWDATA SUCC_TABLE WHERE SUCC_TABLE.STATUS = RD2.STATUS)
  ORDER BY STATUS, ID
  )
)  
SELECT
  L.STATUS, L.LOWER, U.UPPER
FROM 
  LOWER_VALS L
  JOIN UPPER_VALS U ON
    U.RN = L.RN;
```

Results in the set

```
A   1   2

A   6   8

B   3   5

C   9   9
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10184/2

Comment: @Anucha Patthanajan - Please tell us what rdbms you are working with.  You now have 2 answers which look correct, but we are guessing some details.

Answer (score -1):

There is not a lot to go on from what you put, but I think this might work.  I am using T-SQL because I don't know what you are using?

```
SELECT
    min(ID)
    , max(ID)
FROM RawData 
WHERE [Status] = 'A'
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but thought I'd point out your solution would return only one record when the OP is looking for two.  Perhaps you can edit your answer?

Comment: It looks to me as though the OP is asking for a range.  On that basis I think Mike's answer is good.

Comment: @HughJones a range for each "island" as they say.

Comment: He wants a range - but it's "start and stop" of "runs" of A... see Tim's comment about Islands

Comment: I understand 'a range' to be a minimum value and a maximum value: as in the phrases 'the number is in the range 0..99', and 'range check error'

Comment: @HughJones he wants range_s_ for given sequences of As... not just the min and max - as As occur in a "broken" fashion in his samples

Comment: @TimLehner - I have not the first clue how you have arrived at that conclusion.  The OP asked for a range.  You may be right however.

Comment: @HughJones yep, i understand mate. But look at his "result" set... it is followed by "Range of Status A"... it has 2 rows - they represent starts and stops of runs of As

Comment: I understand, I am thinking on how to do this.  It would be best to do it in your code like C#.

Comment: I agree - almost certainly easier and more efficient to calculate the ends of the islands on a row-by-row basis.